# const char** parameter warning about char** argument

Tags: c, char, constants

During compilation of a call to the following function:

```
char* process_array_of_strings(const char** strings);
```

GCC complains when a `char**` is passed as argument:

```
note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
```

While the function does not alter the characters (hence the const) it does duplicate the array of pointers in order to modify the character pointers themselves, so constant pointers are definitely undesirable here.

Compilation succeeds and the program appears to work. So how is the programmer supposed to handle this warning?

Comment: How are you calling that function?

Comment: Ah! The beautiful, golden brown cruft that results from modern c trying to remain compatible with historical practice while benefiting from strict constant correctness.

Comment: @dmckee yes it's a beautiful cruft and all :) but shouldn't it issue a warning when the function accepts a non-const not the other way around ?

Comment: This is FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html. It applies to both C and C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why `char **` is not automatically converted to `const char **` in C++, and why the C compiler issues a warning while allowing it.

```
/* This function returns a pointer to a string through its output parameter: */
void get_some_string(const char ** p) {
    /* I can do this because p is const char **, so the string won't be modified. */
    *p = "unchangeable string in program core";
}

void f() {
    char * str;
    /* First, I'll call this function to obtain a pointer to a string: */
    get_some_string(&str);
    /* Now, modify the string: */
    for (char * p = str; *p; p++)
        *p = toupper(*p);
    /* We have just overwritten a constant string in program core (or crashed). */
}
```

From your description of what `process_array_of_strings()` does, it could just as well take `const char * const *` because it modifies neither the pointers nor the characters (but duplicates the pointers elsewhere). In that case, the above scenario would not be possible, and compiler theoretically *could* allow you to convert `char **` to `const char * const *` automatically without warnings, but that's not how the language is defined.

So the answer is obviously that you need a cast (explicit). I've written up this expanation so that you can fully understand why the warning appears, which is important when you decide to silence one.

Comment: Thanks, great example for helping understanding of this problem.

Comment: But `const char * const *` still provokes the same (similar) response from GCC.

Comment: It does. As I wrote, this is an unfortunate limitation; theoretically, the compiler could convert `char **` to `const char * const *` without warnings, but that's not how it is in reality.

Comment: @Alexey Feldgendler: Strictly speaking, in C language this conversion is exactly as illegal as in C++. Both C and C++ are supposed to generate an "error" in response to this conversion. It is just that historically C compilers were more permitting in this regard.

Comment: @James Morris: In C++ language the const-correctness rules were changed. In C++ it is legal to convert `char **` to `const char *const *`. In C language it is still illegal.

Comment: It's legal in C. The message is just a warning.

Comment: @Alexey Feldgendler: No. It is not legal in C. In C it is a *constraint violation*, i.e. an *error*. Formally, there's no such thing as "just a warning" in C language. The implementation is required to report errors with a *diagnostic message* of any kind. It just so happened that in this case the compiler decided to report  this error with a diagnostic message of "warning" kind.

Comment: @Alexey Feldgendler: In case of gcc (for example), you have to run it in `-pedantic-errors` mode in order to get it to report all errors as  errors and keep "just warnings" as warnings. This one will turn into an error, because it is really an error.

Answer (score 7):

Make the conversion explicit with a cast and the compiler will be happy:

```
process_array_of_strings((const char**) foo);
```

In these cases you have to explicitly say that you know what you're doing.

Comment: Your remarks, and dmckee's are nearly convincing me this is right. Casting did occur to me but wanted to check first.